# Want to add new column which is calculated from existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has call data inserted. Now I want to calculate picktime and close time of call

```
Create table calldata 
(
    calldate Datetime,
    picktime datetime,
    status varchar(50)
)

insert into calldata 
values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:43:57 PM','ATTENDED')

insert into calldata 
values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:44:25 PM','ESCALATED')

insert into calldata 
values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:49:52 PM','ESCALATED')

insert into calldata 
values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:50:20 PM','CLOSED')

select * from calldata
```

Output:

```
calldate                | picktime                 | status
--------------------------------------------------------------
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:43:57.000  | ATTENDED
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:44:25.000  | ESCALATED
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:49:52.000  | ESCALATED
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:50:20.000  | CLOSED
```

Now I want data like this from above table:

```
calldate                | picktime                 |   CloseTime                | status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:43:57.000  |   2016-11-18 16:44:25.000  | ATTENDED
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:44:25.000  |   2016-11-18 16:49:52.00   | ESCALATED
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:49:52.000  |   2016-11-18 16:50:20.00   | CLOSED
2016-11-18 16:43:37.000 | 2016-11-18 16:50:20.000  |                            | CLOSED
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the close_time as the picktime of the next call?

Comment: not for the next call, want close_time for same call from one particular mobile no

Comment: This data is for only one no. I want same for different mobile nos

Comment: From that i want to calculate call duration i.e. picktime-closetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
LEAD(picktime, 1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY calldate ORDER BY picktime)?
```

It gets the next pictime for the same calldate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Begin Tran

Create table calldata (calldate Datetime,picktime datetime,status varchar(50))

insert into calldata values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:43:57 PM','ATTENDED')
insert into calldata values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:44:25 PM','ESCALATED')
insert into calldata values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:49:52 PM','ESCALATED')
insert into calldata values('2016-11-18 04:43:37 PM','2016-11-18 04:50:20 PM','CLOSED')


select calldate,picktime,LEAD(picktime,1) OVER (ORDER BY picktime )as CloseTime,status from calldata
RollBack Tran
```

Answer (score 0):

With subqueries is live easy:

```
select *, 
    (
     select top 1 d.picktime from calldata d 
     where d.picktime > c.picktime
     order by d.picktime asc) previous_picktime
from calldata c
```

This qry do the same work as `LEAD` ranking function (but I prefere use subqry because LEAD doesn't exist on previous versions (for example MSSQL 2008 R2).

If you want to add column it's best way to add this into view.